# A set constructed with the rational numbers is dense in a certain set.

Tags: analysis

Let,
$$\mathbb{Q} = \{q_1,\dots,q_n,\dots \}.$$

Let,
$$I_{n} = q_n  + (-2^{-n},2^{-n}).$$

Let, $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $\mu(B^{c})=0$. Then we define
$$U := \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}I_n.$$

Is $(U \cap B)$ dense in $B$? I'm having trouble showing this one to be true.

Thanks!

Comment: Is $\mu$ Lebesgue measure?